# Case insensitive pattern matching for strings

Tags: scala

```
match (str) {
  case "String1" => ???
  case "String2" => ???
}
```

This is case sensitive matching. How to write case insensitive matching? I know I can call toLowerCase for each branch, but I want more elegant solution.

Comment: Call toLowerCase on `str` this will avoid duplication (obviosly all the case options will need to be lower case then).

Comment: Case options are constants which I cannot modify

Comment: @orionll and you cannot rewrite whole match statement, right? (e.g. replacing plain strings with the regexp matchers)

Comment: I can do anything except modifying the string constants.

Comment: You mentioned `toLowerCase` for each branch but why not `toLowerCase` on the `str`? No need for implicits etc (below)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Basic approach:*

You could use **Pattern Guards** and **Regular Expressions**

```
str match {
case s if s matches "(?i)String1" => 1
case s if s matches "(?i)String2" => 2
case _ => 0
}
```

*Sophisticated method:*

**Implicits** with **String Interpolation** and **Regex**

```
implicit class CaseInsensitiveRegex(sc: StringContext) {
  def ci = ( "(?i)" + sc.parts.mkString ).r
}

def doStringMatch(str: String) = str match {
  case ci"String1" => 1
  case ci"String2" => 2
  case _ => 0
}
```

Some example usage in the REPL:

```
scala> doStringMatch("StRINg1")
res5: Int = 1

scala> doStringMatch("sTring2")
res8: Int = 2
```

Comment: There is a function `String.equalsIgnoreCase`. No need for regular expressions.

Comment: Ha, was just going to suggest that.

Comment: map(_ => "x") was part of another example and is not needed here. It would have added a named capture group based on the last part of the intepolated string with an x added to the end. I adjusted the example and removed unused parts.

Comment: Is there a way we can add multiple case insensitive strings to a case, while performing pattern matching?

Answer (score 8):

Easy solution:

```
val str = "string1"

str toUpperCase match (str) {
  case "STRING1" => ???
  case "STRING2" => ???
}
```

Comment: Seems much more straightforward than other approaches. Any downsides I'm not noticing?

Comment: A possible downside is that you might have problems with case conversion if you don't be careful about locale. For example i might be converted to I or İ depending on the locale setting.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. toLowerCase also works.

Comment: This one is good for string literals. But when you match against constants defined somewhere else (e.g. case MyConstant => ...) this approach becomes problematic.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach that does not depend on regexes or interpolaters:

```
 implicit class StringExtensions(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
    def insensitive = new {
      def unapply(other: String) = s.equalsIgnoreCase(other)
    }
  }

  val test1 = "Bye".insensitive
  val test2 = "HELLo".insensitive

  "Hello" match {
    case test1() => println("bad!")
    case test2() => println("sweet!")
    case _ => println("fail!")
  }
```

Here is another way using interpolaters but no regex:

```
  implicit class StringInterpolations(sc: StringContext) {
    def ci = new {
      def unapply(other: String) = sc.parts.mkString.equalsIgnoreCase(other)
    }
  }

  "Hello" match {
    case ci"Bye" => println("bad!")
    case ci"HELLO" => println("sweet!")
    case _ => println("fail!")
  }
```

The above can also be used to pattern match inside case classes e.g.:

```
case class Dog(name: String)

val fido = Dog("FIDO")

fido match {
  case Dog(ci"fido") => "woof"    
  case _ => "meow :("    
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but if something like this works, that would be really cool! If you can make it work, could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @user247077: Sorry I wrote directly into the answer box and made a typo. Try now - I verified this myself.

Comment: For those wondering, like I was, both the examples rely on the syntax of unapply where the return value is a boolean, (the other two being where return value is an `Opt[T]`, or an `Opt[Seq[T]]`. The second examples syntax might be familiar from s"xyz$a" kind of syntax.