# Best way to perform case insensitive comparison for Scala case class

Tags: scala

I have a case class that represent a Person.

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

I need to perform person comparison based on the first name and last name in case insensitive way, such as:

```
Person("John", "Doe") == Person("john", "Doe") // should return true
```

or in a Seq

```
Seq(Person("John", "Doe")).contains(Person("john", "Doe")
```

The simplest way is to override equals and hashCode methods inside Person case class, but as overwriting equals and hashCode in case class is frowned upon, what will be the best way to do that in a clean way.

Can somebody recommend an idiomatic way to solve this case sensitivity issue?

Thanks,
Suriyanto

Comment: Maybe a type class could be the right choice here. See my answer below.

Comment: Do you *always* want comparisons to be case insensitive or just when desired?

Comment: Always be case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't *compromise* the original meaning of `equals`, `hashCode` and, consequently, `==` for a case class. IMHO the most idiomatic solution here from a functional programming point of view is to use a type class:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)

trait Equal[A] {
  def eq(a1: A, a2: A): Boolean
}

object Equal {
  def areEqual[A : Equal](a1: A, a2: A): Boolean = implicitly[Equal[A]].eq(a1, a2)

  implicit object PersonEqual extends Equal[Person] {
    override def eq(a1: Person, a2: Person): Boolean = a1.firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(a2.firstName) &&
      a1.lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(a2.lastName)
  }
}
```

In a REPL session:

```
scala> import Equal.areEqual
import Equal.areEqual

scala> val p1 = Person("John", "Doe")
p1: Person = Person(John,Doe)

scala> val p2 = p1.copy(firstName = "john")
p2: Person = Person(john,Doe)

scala> areEqual(p1, p2)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> val p3 = p1.copy(lastName = "Brown")
p3: Person = Person(John,Brown)

scala> areEqual(p1, p3)
res1: Boolean = false
```

This way if you need to provide a different equality meaning for `Person` in a given context you can just implement your version of `Equal[Person]` without touching anything else. E.g.: In a given point of your code two `Person` instances are equal if they have the same last name:

```
implicit object PersonLastnameEqual extends Equal[Person] {
  override def eq(a1: Person, a2: Person): Boolean = a1.lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(a2.lastName)
}
```

REPL session:

```
scala> val p1 = Person("John", "Doe")
p1: Person = Person(John,Doe)

scala> val p2 = p1.copy(firstName = "Mary")
p2: Person = Person(Mary,Doe)

scala> areEqual(p1, p2)
res0: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perform some "normalization" at Person construction:

```
sealed trait Person {
  def firstName:String
  def lastName:String
}

object Person {
  def apply(firstName:String, lastName:String):Person = PersonNormalized(firstName.toLowerCase, lastName.toLowerCase)

  private case class PersonNormalized(firstName:String, lastName:String) extends Person
}
```

Its up to you to decide if it better than overriding equals and hashCode

Comment: I thought of this solution, but the user would like to see their names the way they entered it. In this solution, when we display the names, then user will see all lower after normalization.

Comment: You could store both: `private case class PersonNormalized(firstName:String, lastName:String)(originalFirstName: String, originalLastName: String)` and override `toString`.

Answer (score 1):

> The simplest way is to override equals and hashCode methods inside Person case class, but as overwriting equals and hashCode in case class is frowned upon

It's perfectly acceptable to override them provided your implementations fulfill [the contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). The only problem is that it needs to be updated if `Person` changes, but other solutions would as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal class (not `case`) and write `equals`/`hashcode` for them. IDE-s usually got snippets for that (because they're necessary in Java).

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    override def hashCode = ???
    override def equals = ???
}
```

Alternatively, if we're in solving "XY problem", you should write your broader concerns/goals. Maybe, in reality, you should have some `Map` and `case class`-es with lower-cased names only, or a `Long` token inside a DB. Just guessing...

Comment: Thanks. If I turn all my case classes to regular class, then I might end up to have the majority of my classes as regular class and have to rewrite quite a few built-in functionality from case class (copy, apply, etc) for each of them. I wonder if I am supposed to overwrite hashCode and equals on regular class, why shouldn't I overwrite them in the case class in the first place?

Comment: You may searx/duckduckgo/google for that, it is of course a very popular question. In short: `hashCode` and `equals` are needed if you use them, e.c. for putting inside a `Map` (`HashMap`).

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive comparison of all members of `Person` consider a (lower cased) string of their values, as follows,

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
  def ==(that: Person) = {
    val thisStr = this.productIterator.mkString.toLowerCase
    val thatStr = that.productIterator.mkString.toLowerCase
    thisStr == thatStr
  }
}
```

Hence

```
Person("john","Doe") == Person("john","doe")
true

Person("john","Doe") == Person("john","smith")
false
```

Comment: 1. `Person("john","Doe") == (Person("john","doe"): Any)` will be false. 2. Override `equals` instead of implementing a `==` method (this handles `null`s incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend changing the functionality of `==` for a case class, but you could create a new operator which has the meaning of a case insensitive comparison:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String) {

  def toUpper = 
    this.copy(firstName = firstName.toUpperCase, lastName = lastName.toUpperCase)

  def =~=(that: Person) = this.toUpper == that.toUpper
}

Person("john", "smith") =~= Person("JoHn", "SmiTH") //true

Seq(
  Person("JoHn", "SmiTH"),
  Person("Jack", "Jones")
).exists(_ =~= Person("john", "smith")) //true
```

If you want something more specific than `.exists`:

```
implicit class PersonSeq(s: Seq[Person]) {

  def containsInsensitive(p: Person) = s.exists(_ =~= p)
}

Seq(
  Person("JoHn", "SmiTH"),
  Person("Jack", "Jones")
).containsInsensitive(Person("john", "smith"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using string interpolations (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28445089/471136):

```
implicit class StringInterpolations(sc: StringContext) {
  def ci = new {
    def unapply(other: String) = sc.parts.mkString.equalsIgnoreCase(other)
  }
}

"Hello" match {
  case ci"Bye" => println("bad!")
  case ci"HELLO" => println("sweet!")
  case _ => println("fail!")
}

Person("John", "Doe") match {
  case Person(ci"john", ci"Doe") => 
  case _ => assert(false)
}
```