# Scala: using a string argument with an implicit expecting string context

Tags: scala, implicit

I have implemented this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115778/4631376
(the second one with the implicit class)
and i'm trying to use "ci" with a string argument rather than a literal string

```
implicit class CaseInsensitiveRegex(sc: StringContext) {
   def ci = ("(?i)" + sc.parts.mkString).r
}

 def Refiner(uid: String) = new ActionRefiner[Input, Output] {
     override protected def refine[A](request: Input[A]): Future[Either[Result, Output[A]]] = {
       uid match {
            case ci"${request.auid}" => Future.successful(Right(new Output[A](request.auid, request)))
  }
}
```

}

but it doesn't seem to works since the string context "sc" is empty.
and it should contain the content of "request.auid"

it works well with literal strings (sending the content like "abcabc").

thoughts?

Comment: Please include the full code to reproduce your problem, along with expected input/ouput and any existing error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal extractor looks like an apply `case X(x)` but instead of taking a value, it binds the name `x`. Same thing when your interpolation is desugared.

See [the scala hacking blog](http://hacking-scala.org/post/50360896036/regular-expressions-interpolation-in-pattern) and [how to exploit Dynamic for parameterized extractors](http://hacking-scala.org/post/49051516694/introduction-to-type-dynamic).